# search using two filters in spring-data-elasticsearch java api

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use filters in spring-data-elasticsearch java api. I understand that I can use andFilter to search based on two fields like this

```
builder.withFilter(FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("DATE").gte(startDate).lt(endDate), FilterBuilders.boolFilter().mustNot(FilterBuilders.termFilter("STATUS", "ACTIVE"))));
```

but in the code i have some if conditions and thus I cannot use andFilter directly to search ... take a look at this example

```
    if("MSGSTAT".equals("SENT")) {
            builder.withFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("DATE").gte(startDate).lt(endDate));
        }
    if("STATUS".equals("ACTIVE")) {
    builder.withFilter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().mustNot(FilterBuilders.termFilter("STATUS", "ACTIVE")));
}
```

When I use filters in the above mentioned way it doesn't applies the and keyword and the result received is incorrect. I also tried to do it this way but it didn't help either

```
builder.withFilter(FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("DATE").gte(startDate).lt(endDate))); 

builder.withFilter(FilterBuilders.andFilter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter().mustNot(FilterBuilders.termFilter("STATUS", "ACTIVE"))));
```

How should I do it making sure that the AND aggregation is always applied when using if conditions

Comment: In the second code section there is no obvious "and" keyword. How would your Filter have to look like if you build it with json?

Comment: i tried it that way also, just to check what it would do. Since in the json format all the search criteria are to be mentioned in the single and section i guess i will have to do it by putting all my conditions with one andFilter() in java api

Comment: Maybe you could write Implementation of Custom Repository and use @Query Annotation with your Filter.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer ...
I created a reference variable of type AndFilterBuilder and added all my filters to it using the add() and then built the Query Builder

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder builder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
AndFilterBuilder filters = null;
filters = new AndFilterBuilder(<your filter>);
filters.add(<your filter>);
builder.withFilter(filters);
builder.build()
```

Comment: NativeSearchQueryBuilder cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Hi Renu, which jar are you using?

Comment: Elastic search 1.4 jar

Comment: The current example mentions the use of spring implementation of the elastic search api.